# error when calling char to allow user to enter choice

Tags: c++

I am writing a simple text game in C++. The user has the option of choosing the left room or the right room. I did have this set up as an int statement: enter 1 for left, enter 2 for right. Now I would like to have the user enter left for left room, right for right room.

I replaced the int with char, but I am getting an error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    char decision;
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == left) {
        cout << "went left" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> Error: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Did you read the error? And look up "_How to `get char ()` from a user_" if you want it as a char, or declare `decision` as an int if you want it as int

Comment: the error reads "Comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'std::__1::iOS_base & (*)(std::__1::iOS_base&)')

Comment: Show the code. Enough code that when it's compiled it shows the error; nothing more.

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    char decision;
   
    cout << "You enter the dungeon. There is a door way to the right, and a door way to the left."
            " For left door enter Left. For right door enter right" << endl;
    cin >> decision;
    if(decision == left)

Comment: Where you have declared left 'variable' ??

Comment: char decision is the variable. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @thejdah Put additional information in your question please. Code in comments isn't helpful.

Comment: The answer below solved my problem. In future questions I will place the code in the original post. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `char` stands for a single character - what you need is a string (multiple characters).
2. when you actually have the user's value in `decision` you need to compare it to the string `"left"` rather than just `left` which the compiler tries to interpret as a symbol (like a variable name).

All in all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string decision;
    cin >> decision;

    if (decision == "left") {
        cout << "went left" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think he in his case doesn't need getline but only >> operator because he only needs "right" or "left"; no white spaces assumed

Comment: @Raindrop7 thx, i updated the answer (it didn't compile for me cause I used the wrong direction of `>>` so I thought cin's operator>> didn't exist for strings).

Comment: @Amon Zilca  you're welcome!.   extraction operator (>>) works with strings but stops reading when reaching the first white space or the end of line. I compiled your very code and it works

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way use strcmp:

```
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

    char decision[50] = "";
    std::cout << "Decision: ";
    std::cin.get(decision, 50, '\n');

    if( !(strcmp(decision, "left")) )
        std::cout << "left";
    else
        if( !(strcmp(decision, "right")) )
            std::cout << "right";
    else
        std::cout << "bad input!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

- you should also make no difference between lowercase and uppercase because if a user enters "Left" instead "left" then it won't work